# Warning: Undefined array key php

Tags: php, html, mysql, array

Cuando quiero agarrar la información de un input en PHP mediante $_get y un array, me dice que la variable no esta definida, a continuación mi código:

```html
<div>

    <form action="">
        <label>Usuario:</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="txtuser"><br>
        <label>Email:</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="txtemail"><hr>
        <input type="submit" name="" vlaue="Agregar">
        <a href="index.php">Volver atras</a>
    </form>

</div>

<?php 

    include 'conexion.php';
    $user=$_GET['txtuser'];
    $email=$_GET['txtemail'];
    if($user!=null||$email!=null){
        $sql="INSERT INTO users('ID','Usuario','Email') VALUES('.$user.','.$email.','')";
        mysqli_query($sql);
        if ($user=1) {
            header("location:index.php");
        }
    }

?>
```

El error que me da, me dice lo siguiente:

```html
Warning: Undefined array key "txtuser" in C:\xampp\htdocs\Taliloco_world_\agregar.php on line 17

Warning: Undefined array key "txtemail" in C:\xampp\htdocs\Taliloco_world_\agregar.php on line 18
```

No se si la variable la tengo que declarar antes, o que estoy poniendo mal, ayuda por favor...

Comment: Prueba ```if (isset($_Get['submit'])) { tu código }``` y al input de tipo sumbit añádele ```name="submit"```

Answer (score 5):

Cuando mandas un formulario, los `input` que no tienen datos no son enviados, por tanto, si intentas recuperar alguno de esos datos no enviados tendrás derecho a un *`Undefined index`*, como de hecho ocurre en tu caso.

En la prehistoria se usaba `isset()` para controlar esta situación, de hecho, por lo general te sugerirán su uso y en la mayoría de tutoriales verás esa práctica (ten cuidado con los tutoriales prehistóricos, son particularmente abundantes en el caso de PHP). Bueno, usar `isset()` no está mal, no está prohibido... pero es prehistoria. Las cosas cambiaron mucho desde PHP 7 y más aún en PHP 8 y muchas cosas verbosas son ahora más simples. Significa que hay formas más elegantes, más limpias y más modernas de resolver esto.

**Desde PHP 7+** puedes usar el [operador de *fusión de null*](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration70.new-features.php) de este modo:

```
include 'conexion.php';
$user=$_GET['txtuser']   ?? null;
$email=$_GET['txtemail'] ?? null;
if($user && $email){
    #Riesgo de consulta descabellada, ver Post-Data
    $sql="INSERT INTO users(ID,Usuario,Email) VALUES('$user','$email','')";
    mysqli_query($sql);
    if ($user=1) {
        header("location:index.php");
    }
}
```

En el código anterior, si alguno de los valores no es enviando, la variable tendrá el valor `null`. Luego en el `if` verificamos en positivo, para menos confusiones.

En **PHP anterior a la versión 7** puedes usar un [*operador ternario*](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php), porque en esas versiones no existe *fusión de null*:

```
include 'conexion.php';
$user =!empty($_GET['txtuser'])  ? $_GET['txtuser']  : null;
$email=!empty($_GET['txtemail']) ? $_GET['txtemail'] : null;
if($user && $email){
    #Riesgo de consulta descabellada, ver Post-Data
    $sql="INSERT INTO users(ID,Usuario,Email) VALUES('$user','$email','')";
    mysqli_query($sql);
    if ($user=1) {
        header("location:index.php");
    }
}
```

El concepto es el mismo, sólo que hay que verificar con `empty()` si hay datos o no.

#### Post-Data

Tu código es altamente vulnerable a ataques de *inyección SQL*, considera usar consultas preparadas para neutralizar ese gravísimo agujero de seguridad.

Por otra parte, tu consulta `INSERT` podría no tener sentido. Estás colocando el valor de `$user` en la columna `ID`, el valor de `$email` para la columna `Usuario` y una cadena vacía para la columna `Email`, aparte de usar comillas para los nombres de columna. Si usas comillas, no serán reconocidas como columnas.

Comment: A parte de que el imput submit NO tiene value=" " si no vlaue=" "